# right outer join between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

i have 2 tables, one is called `Classes` which contains the `ClassName` and one is called `FullSchedule` which contains info including `ClassName`, `DayVal` and `TimeVal`.

What i want to do is, i want to select the classes that are not being using in a particular day and time, and this is my query :

```
    SELECT `Classes`.`ClassName`
    FROM `FullSchedule`
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN `Classes`
    ON `FullSchedule`.`ClassName` = `Classes`.`ClassName`
    WHERE `FullSchedule`.`DayVal` = '$day' AND `FullSchedule`.`TimeVal` = `$time`
```

the result is the classes that are bing used(the common ones) though im using `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and even if i change it to :

```
ON `FullSchedule`.`ClassName` != `Classes`.`ClassName`
```

it shows me all classes, no matter how i change it, it either get me all of the classes or just the classes that are being used. how to i get the classes that are not being used?

Comment: Note that no one actually uses RIGHT JOIN. Nothing wrong it - it's just a little counter-intuitive for many humans (including me) - but perhaps that's a western, left-to-right writing thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `Classes`.`ClassName`
    FROM `Classes`
WHERE Classes`.`ClassName` not in ( 
SELECT `FullSchedule`.`ClassName`
FROM `FullSchedule`
WHERE `FullSchedule`.`DayVal` = '$day' AND `FullSchedule`.`TimeVal` = `$time` )
```

Comment: i've tried both, and still not working, its giving me all classes :/

Comment: Are you sure that you have classes with same name in FullSchedule and Classes tables?

Comment: SELECT `Classes`.`ClassName`
    FROM `Classes`
WHERE Classes`.`ClassName` not in ( 
SELECT `FullSchedule`.`ClassName`
FROM `FullSchedule`)
Try this query, do you get all classes?

Comment: it returned Zero rows !

Comment: Then problem in variables $day and $time.
Query are fine.

Answer (score 1):

At first retrieve data with `WHERE` conditions from table `FullSchedule`, then `RIGHT JOIN` it to `Classes` :

```
SELECT 
    c.`ClassName`
FROM (
    SELECT 
      `ClassName`
    FROM
      `FullSchedule`
    WHERE
      `DayVal` = '$day' AND `TimeVal` = '$time'
) f RIGHT OUTER JOIN `Classes` c
ON f.`ClassName` != c.`ClassName`
```

Comment: @Ibraheem Ismail : `echo` your query, copy output and execute it in your sql administration tool (like phpmyadmin). If it returns zero rows, then problem is in your database otherwise, if it returns error, you will be absolutely sure that the suggested query is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the JOIN option:

```
SELECT c.ClassName
FROM   Classes c
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                   FROM   FullSchedule fs 
                   WHERE fs.DayVal = $day
                     AND fs.TimeVal = $time
                     AND fs.ClassName = c.ClassName )
```

I suggest you put all three solutions in your analyzer and compare the execution plans to find out which is the best fit for your environment.

If the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` syntax is absolutely necessary:

```
SELECT c.ClassName
FROM   FullSchedule fs
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN Classes c
         ON  fs.ClassName = c.ClassName
         AND fs.DayVal = $day
         AND fs.TimeVal = $time
WHERE  fs.ClassName IS NULL
```

The `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` ensures the `Classes` table returns all of its rows and then matches `FullSchedule` rows on `ClassName` and those with `DayVal` and `TimeVal` values equal to `$day` and `$time` respectively.

The `WHERE` clause eliminates the rows where the `FullSchedule` table (with the `ClassName`, `DayVal`, and `TimeVal` restrictions) does not have a matching record.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT c.ClassName
   FROM classes c
   LEFT 
   JOIN FullSchedule s
     ON s.ClassName = c.ClassName
    AND s.DayVal = '$day' 
    AND s.TimeVal = '$time' -- <-- NOT BACKTICKS
  WHERE s.ClassName IS NULL;
```

Consider storing dates and times as a single entity. Much, much better idea.